# How to get Hijri month based on time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, hijri

I am trying to get **Hijri month**

**For example**

> if `Time` part is less than `04:00:00`, then **Day-1** and get month of that date

Ex: Gregorian Date '2019-06-04 03:42:37.030'  = Hijri date 1-09-1440(dd-MM-yyyy)

**Expecting Output**

```
Month
-----
  08   //because time is less than 4:00:00 AM
```

Ex: Gregorian Date '2019-06-04 04:42:37.030'  = Hijri date 1-09-1440(dd-MM-yyyy)

**Expecting Output**

```
Month
-----
  09   //because time is greater than 4:00:00 AM
```

> Else same day month

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convert` to get your Hijri date:

```
convert(varchar(10),<your column> ,131)
```

We can combine that with a case statement and dateadd to handle your time requirement.

```
case when cast(<your column> as time) < '04:00:00'
then convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,<your column>),131)
else 
convert(varchar(10),<your column>) end
```

Finally, you can use substring (and patindex) to pull out your month. (Extract and such don't work with this date format.)

```
select
substring(
  derived_hijri_date,
  patindex('%[/]%', derived_hijri_date) + 1,
  2)
from
(
select
 case when cast(<your column> as time) < '04:00:00'
  then convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,<your column>),131)
 else 
  convert(varchar(10),<your column>,131) end as derived_hijri_date
from
 <your table>
) t
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e952e/35)